# MVC 3.0 + jQueryMobile + FormAuth: Can I force a dialog-like transition for the form auth, when invoked directly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor

I have a MVC 3.0 / RAZOR web app using jQueryMobile, with Form Authentication on part tof the site.

The Form Authentication page is composed by this layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Some title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">                
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div data-role="dialog" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="e">        
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            @if ((ViewBag.HideTitle == null) || (!ViewBag.HideTitle))
            {
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
            }
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">   
            @RenderBody()
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the actual page:

```
@model MyApp.Web.App.Models.LogOnModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/DialogLayout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Sign In</h3>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Authentication failed")

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <p />
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <p /><p />

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { data_theme = "a" })
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe )

      <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" datatheme="b">Sign In</button></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

The authentication / dialog transition works correctly when you click on a link from an already loaded page.

For example:
- Home/Index (unauthenticated)
- Click on "authenticated link" /Home/MyAuthenticatedPage

In this case, the jQueryMobile framework calls the page through ajax, gets the redirect to /Account/LogOn and displays the /Account/LogOn page as a dialog box correctly.

When an authenticated page is called directly from browser though, the page is loaded but shown only the background. This is true either going to /Home/MyAuthenticated page or going directly to /Account/LogOn through the browser.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to this and the latest version of jquery resolved it.